# check that each file in this folder is the latest version

Tags: translation, grammar, word-choice

In my learning of Chinese, I am exploring two related sentences:
the first is the simple statement
Each file in this folder is the latest version

```
里 这个 文件夹 的 文件部 最新的版本
```

Or perhaps, one should or could  leave out the translation for the word version and simply write:
里 这个 文件夹 的 文件部 最新

In English, one can use the word “copy” instead of “version”
Thus, could one write the above as:
里 这个 文件夹 的 文件部 最新的 抄件

the next question is making the imperative:
please make sure that each file in this folder is the latest version

你 保证  里 这个 文件夹 的 文件部 最新

Just because I learned it, I like the “check” verb.
你 检查 里 这个 文件夹 的 文件部 最新
你 核实 里 这个 文件夹 的 文件部 最新
你 查证 里 这个 文件夹 的 文件部 最新

Of course, this post would not be complete without including the result of Google Translate (which I looked at after I worked on this myself)!

该文件夹中的每个文件都是当前版本

确保该文件夹中的每个文件都是当前版本

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You translated "In this folder" to "里(inside) 这个文件夹(this folder)" showing that you don't know one major difference between English and Chinese grammar when it comes to preposition

The prepositions "in/ on/ at ..." in English are placed before the noun, but in Chinese, the preposition is placed chiefly after the noun

Example:

- [**in**] the folder = (在)文件夾[**內**] --> 文件夾[**內**]
- [**on**] the table = (在)枱[**上**] --> 枱[**上**]
- [**at**] the party = (在)派對[**中**]--> 派對[**中**]

> The files [inside/ in] this folder

> [里] 这个 文件夹 的 文件 (X)

> 这个 文件夹 [里] 的 文件 (O)

You missed the verb "are" in your translation

> 这个 文件夹 里 的 文件 最新的版本 (the files in this folder the newest version) (X)

> 这个 文件夹 里 的 文件部 [是] 最新的版本 (the files in this folder [are] the newest version) (O)

Check (to see) = 确認

> [确認] 这个 文件夹 里 的 文件 是 最新的版本 = [check to confirm] the files in this folder are the latest version

Another way to say the same thing:

> [看看] 这个 文件夹 里 的 文件 [是否] 最新的版本 = [see] The files in this folder [ is or isn't] the latest version

Replace "check"(确認) with "see"(看看) to make it more conversational; write [是否](is or isn't) instead of 是 to emphasize uncertainty.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean use a programme to check the meta-data? Or how will you check?

You can express what you want like this:

Each file in this folder is the latest version.
此文件夹中的每个文件都是最新版本。

Please make sure that each file in this folder is the latest version.
请确保这个文件夹里的每个文件都是最新版本。